# How to use compile different file extension such as "a.test" not ".c .cpp" on gcc or g++ compiler

Tags: c, linux, gcc

I want to compile different file extension such as "a.test" not ".c .cpp" on gcc or g++ compiler

example) a.test

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   printf("file extension test \n");
}
```

**gcc -o a a.test -??**

Can I use it like this?

If I can use this, please let me know the option or method.

If I can't use this, tell me it's impossible.

Comment: Have you *tried* it? What happens when you do?

Comment: Hello SaymoinSam. It was because I thought it might be a good idea to create a system that distinguishes functions by extension in a directory.

Comment: I would recommend using sub-directories to separate different parts of your code instead.

Comment: Hello Some programmer dude. I already tried it with -x option but I wondered if there were better opinions from experts.

Comment: @tjdnfka2001, If you use the extension idea, you can still do `a.test.c` to keep with the thematic naming and a real extension.

Comment: Hello super. It's just an idea.
I don't know what made you feel so bad, but I'm sorry if you didn't like it. I've already tried with the -x option and finshed test
but I was just wondering if there were better opinions from experts.

Comment: FWIW to people, a naming convention can have advantages. As an example, you can get CTest to autoregister build-pass and build-fail tests with some custom discovery code. Of course that also comes with the same disadvantages other filesystem-scanning tricks have.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/380558/compiling-c-source-file-without-c-suffix. (While AskUbuntu definitely is not a good place for programming questions).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll assume you have a sensible reason to do this. With that assumption the [gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html) describes the option that can be used to do it:

> -x language
>
> Specify explicitly the language for the following input files (rather than letting the compiler choose a default based on the file name suffix). This option applies to all following input files until the next -x option.

So in your example, compiling as a C file would be:

```
gcc -x c -o a a.test
```

Comment: @tjdnfka2001 -- while this is possible, I'd suggest thinking hard about whether you really ought to do it. It's probably fine if you're the only person who will ever look at the code, but nobody else will understand your naming. Linux users aren't in thrall to filename extensions in the way that Windows and Android users are but, nevertheless, we all kind-of expect C source files to end in `.c`. I'm sure there are other ways to apply a naming convention, that do not require using unconventional filename extensions.